# long array in java declared initialization failed

Tags: java, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array, initialization

In the following program:

```
public static long Coinsum(int euro) {
    double[] coins= {0,0.01,0.02,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2};
    long numberoftimes[][];

    for(int i=0;i<coins.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=euro;j++) {
            if(i==0 &&j==0){
                numberoftimes[i][j]=1;
            }
            else if(i<j){
                numberoftimes[i][j]=numberoftimes[i-1][j]+numberoftimes[i][j-i];
            }
            else {
                numberoftimes[i][j]=numberoftimes[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return numberoftimes[coins.length-1][euro];
}
```

`numberoftimes` shows a warning inside my for loops:

> local variable numberoftimes may not have been initialized

what should I do?

Comment: It would be nice if you could update your question with a problem statement.  What is your code trying to do?

Comment: This code will almost certainly crash at runtime, because you never initialize `numberoftimes[][]`.  You need something like `long numberoftimes[][] = new long[10][10]`

Comment: Do exactly what the warning is saying: initialize numberoftimes

Comment: oh sorry new here...its the coin change problem ...it needs to return the number of possible combinations which can be used to make a certain amount of money..in my case euro is the amount of money and coins are the coins i have to make all possible combinations..if something doesnt make sense let me know...i am greek so my english are not perfect

Comment: Edited to improve code formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `new` a `long[][]`. That can be jagged (but isn't here). The first dimension is `coins.length`, and the second is `euro + 1`. Java naming conventions are lowercase initial camelCase. Regardless, it might look something like

```
public static long coinSum(int euro) {
    double[] coins = { 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2 };
    long[][] numberoftimes = new long[coins.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
        numberoftimes[i] = new long[euro + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j <= euro; j++) {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                numberoftimes[i][j] = 1;
            } else if (i < j) {
                numberoftimes[i][j] = numberoftimes[i - 1][j] + numberoftimes[i][j - i];
            } else {
                numberoftimes[i][j] = numberoftimes[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return numberoftimes[coins.length - 1][euro];
}
```

Comment: thanks  it runs now but since my professor has made a package where itautomatically checks if our code is correct for the particular task my code shows that it is wrong..the problem is that i think my code is right...our professor wants it to return  the number of possible combinations to make the euro variable using the coins that we have...

Answer (score 0):

It should be `long numberoftimes[][] = new long[coins.length][euro+1];`

Comment: `j <= euro`, so you need `euro + 1`.